# get contract creator's address in a different separate smart contract

Tags: solidity

I want to create a dApp where one can do certain things related to a contract they've deployed. let's say it'll be used to manage a token listing site.

I need to figure out how to verify that the address that's calling the functions matches the address that created a particular contract.

eg. 0x01 is the contract creator of Contract A

0x01 calls a function along with the parameter of Contract A's contract address in Contract B

A function within Contract B then finds the contract creator's address of Contract A somehow and matches that against 0x01

Is this possible to do in solidity?

Answer (score 2):

### Code

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

contract A {
    
    address private owner_;
    
    function A() public {
        owner_ = msg.sender;   
    }
    
    function getOwner() public view returns (address) {
        return owner_;
    }
}

contract B {
    
    function findAsOwner() public view returns (bool) {
        require(A(address of contract A).getOwner() == msg.sender);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I tested it on my remix. I called `findAsOwner()` and it passed the `require` part and returned true. You may use this pattern.

Comment: what if contract A is some exisiting contract we can't add code to like https://etherscan.io/address/0x86fa049857e0209aa7d9e616f7eb3b3b78ecfdb0

Comment: I think it can help you a little. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12903/find-the-creator-of-a-contract
Any solidity methods or native web3, get, etc doesn't seem to have the method.